# How to calculate number of unique data in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I'm very new beginner in mongoDB.

> we have  to show output data in which having
>
> 1. Unique number of user by date.
> 2. Number of Android user and Ios user.

This is input JSON data

**Input**

```
[{
  'name' : 'user1',
  'date' : '23/09/2017',
  'deviceType' : 'Android'
 },
{
 'name' : 'user2',
 'date' : '24/09/2017',
 'deviceType' :'ios'
},
{
'name' : 'user1',
'date' : '23/09/2017',
'deviceType' :'ios'
},
{
'name' : 'user2',
'date' : '23/09/2017',
'deviceType' :'ios'
},
{
'name' : 'user1',
'date' : '24/09/2017',
'deviceType' :'ios'
},
{
'name' : 'user2',
'date' : '25/09/2017',
'deviceType' :'Android'
}   
]
```

I'm very confused what is query to fetch required data.

*And Output is*

**Output**

```
   [{
    'date' : '23/09/2017',
    'iosCount': 2,
    'androidCount':1
   }, 
  {
   'date' : '24/09/2017',
   'iosCount': 2,
   'androidCount':0
  },
  {
   'date' : '25/09/2017',
  'iosCount': 0,
  'androidCount':1
 }
]
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution, and it is neutral to device types.  If you add more, the agg pipeline will adapt to the new values.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {d:"$date",t:"$deviceType"}, n: {$sum:1}}}
,{$group: {_id: "$_id.d", devices: {$push: {type:"$_id.t", n:"$n"}} }}
                ]);

{
"_id" : "24/09/2017",
"devices" : [
    {
        "type" : "ios",
        "n" : 2
    }
]
{
"_id" : "23/09/2017",
"devices" : [
    {
        "type" : "ios",
        "n" : 2
    },
    {
        "type" : "Android",
        "n" : 1
    }
]
}
{
"_id" : "25/09/2017",
"devices" : [
    {
        "type" : "Android",
        "n" : 1
    }
]
}
```

If you really want exactly the output you seek:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$date",
        iosCount: {$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq: [ "$deviceType","ios"]}, 1, 0 ] }},
        androidCount: {$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq: ["$deviceType","Android"]}, 1, 0] }}
        }}
                ]);
```

Comment: @ Buzz Moschetti, Please see the Raghav's comment .If there is such type of condition then I want to just kind of data.
[{'date' : 23/09/2017, totalIos : 2, totalAndroid: 1}]
According to your condition it print like
[{'date' : 23/09/2017, totalIos : 2, totalAndroid: 2}] But I'm not intrested in this output. Thanks!

Comment: Ok.  If you want the grouping by name as well, change to:
{$group: {_id: {u:"$name",d:"$date"},

Answer (score 1):

@ Buzz Moschetti

If date "23/09/2017" has input data like

```
[{'name' : 'user1','date' : '23/09/2017','deviceType' : 'Android'},
 {'name' : 'user1','date' : '23/09/2017','deviceType' :'ios'},
 {'name' : 'user1','date' : '23/09/2017','deviceType' : 'Android'},
 {'name' : 'user2','date': '23/09/2017','deviceType':'ios'}]
```

output

```
[{'date' : 23/09/2017, totalIos : 2, totalAndroid: 1}]
```

user1 has data 2 android and 1 Ios data. So only 1 android data will be count.